# Converting Geocoordinate to byte array

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to convert a Geocoordinate of the System.device.location library to a byte array for sending over TCP.

At the moment I'm trying this:

```
    public static byte[] GeoCoordToByteArray(GeoCoordinate coord)
    {
        var binFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        var mStream = new MemoryStream();
        binFormatter.Serialize(mStream, coord);

        return mStream.ToArray();
    }
```

I got the error:System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate' in Assembly 'System.Device, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serialize.

If that means it's not serializable, how can I convert it to a byte array? I'm not experienced with it so bare with please, thanks

Comment: Your question is far too broad. Without a type being marked as serializable, you'll need to implement serialization yourself. But how to do that depends on a variety of factors, primarily exactly what aspects of `GeoCoordinate` you want to keep. You can create your own container type and serialize that, or you can just use something like `BinaryWriter` to write the individual values explicitly, just to name a couple of options.

Comment: ah ok, i just wanted to long and lat so it would probably be eaiser to just make them into doubles, join them and turn that into a byte array, thanks though :)